# Having problems after redirecting website https

Tags: html, http, https

I have this grid boxes for my latest news which looks like this:

[Everything works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qaruv.png)

Now I tried to redirecting my website to HTTPS and suddenly my date and time wont work.

[Date and Time doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo6xc.png)

I tried changing the date and time link to HTTPS but it still won't work

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's my html code:

```html
<div class="col_seventh up">
       <div class="hover panel">
         <div class="front">
        <div class="box7">
          <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="no" clocktype="html5" style="overflow:hidden;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;width:250px;height:250px;" src="https://www.clocklink.com/html5embed.php?clock=039&timezone=AWST&color=black&size=250&Title=&Message=&Target=&From=2017,1,1,0,0,0&Color=black"></iframe>
        </div>
         </div>
         <div class="back">
        <div class="box8">
          <iframe id="forecast_embed" frameborder="0" height="280" width="100%" src="https://forecast.io/embed/#lat=14.5995&lon=120.9842&name=Manila&color=#00aaff&font=Calibri&units=uk"></iframe>
        </div>
         </div>
       </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does your console throw any error? about the HTTPS issue when re-directed?

Comment: @Jorden1337 Not really, I don't get any errors

Comment: reason being is you probably don't have an SSL certificate to serve that date/time over HTTPS.

Comment: You cannot serve _non-https_ content in an iframe in a page loaded with SSL. Likewise, you cannot serve _https_ content in an iframe if the domain does not support _https_ content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `www.clocklink.com` you use in iframe. It has no SSL certificate. I have tried to open in new tab. https not works but in http. So If your site is in https then you cannot use the clocklink site in iframe with http.

Plese find a new clock widget which also works in https.